# Viewing JSON on client side javascript sent from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to view some JSON in the chrome console that was sent by a NodeJS file.  I'm not getting an error but I cannot see the message "hello world"

The NodeJS file sends the JSON message once an HTML form is filled out and the button is pushed.  Therefore the nodeJS sends the message with an app.post.

I receive the JSON with a client-side JavaScript Fetch api and I think I'm getting it in the chrome console but I can't see the message "Hello World".

Is there something I need to put in my client-side javascript to make the json viewable or do I need to send it differently from the NodeJS app?  Something like json.stringify?

Thanks

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()


//enables body parser to get information from HTML
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
//enables nodejs to see css images and other misc files

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/images"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/js"))



app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.get("/admin", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/admin.html')
})

app.post("/admin", function(req, res){
        res.json({message: 'hello world'})
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is open!")
});
```

Client-side JS

```
fetch('/admin')
.then(response =>{
    console.log(response)
    return response.json
})
.then(obj => {
   
    console.log(obj)
})
.catch(error =>{
    console.log("THERE WAS AN ERROR")
})
```

What I'm seeing in chrome console

[image: Chrome Console Results]

Update: I've discovered that I am sending HTML from NodeJS and not JSON and this is causing the error.  I discovered this by changing my client-side JS to text() which gave me a good visual as to what I was receiving from the NodeJS app.  I learned this from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcEmaTVIE24&list=PL-ygtjtXL1J-2HybUi_QRCRnyAoGNupvq&index=1&ab_channel=DaveCeddia

the line of code I changed was:

return response.text()

I still need to figure out how to format the NodeJS in a way that sends the JSON object to chrome console that says "hello world".  Thanks for your help so far everyone.

Comment: try to click on the little triangle next to the response to expand it and tell show us what you see

Comment: i opened the triangle and it is not in there

Answer (score 1):

You must invoke the json function on the response. Now you are just returning the function.

change it to: `return response.json()`

Comment: `
fetch('/admin')
.then(response =>{
    console.log(response)
    return response.json
})
.then(obj => {
    console.log(obj)
    return obj.json
    
    
})
.catch(error =>{
    console.log("THERE WAS AN ERROR")
})` gave me the same output in console

Comment: I forgot to add () onto obj.json() and ran it, the result was it triggered the catch error.